# Getting different terms from different rows for the same node with Feeds

Tags: 7, feeds

I have a kind of weird CSV file to import. The structure is like that:

ID| TITLE| TERMS
1 | Title1 | term1
1 | Title1 | term2
2 | Title2 | term3
2 | Title2 | term1
3 | Title2 | term5

I would like to get all the terms from different lines to the same node. In the end, the node with "Title 1" will have taxonomy terms of "term1" and "term2".

If I directly run the importer, I know that only last value will be taken to the term field.

In short, I would like to get multiple terms from different rows to the same node.

Anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I ended up with a custom php script placed inside the Drupal root. The script reads the csv line-by-line, checks the node if the term exists, if it doesnt exist, adds it to taxonomy term reference field table and taxonomy index table. Taxonomy nidex table is important because views, etc uses it to generate output.